# Integrating react-native into existing Android App

Tags: android, react-native

we are trying to integrate react-native into our existing android application:
The SDK requirements of our build.gradle are:
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23

We use an Intent to call the initial React index.js:

```
Intent inte = new Intent(this, ReactNativeStarter.class);
startActivity(inte);
```

The rest of the code is from the react integrating tutorial.

When we try to call our react component we get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' 
     (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/data/at.??????/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.react-react-native-0.20.1_3762d580ab3ced1fa2f7503493d38e666994b9fa-classes.dex)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule.<init>(NetInfoModule.java:55)
```

Can you help?

Full error log:

```
12-19 10:07:22.157 30271-32680/at.???? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: at.?????, PID:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' 
     (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/data/at.??????/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.react-react-native-0.20.1_3762d580ab3ced1fa2f7503493d38e666994b9fa-classes.dex)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule.<init>(NetInfoModule.java:55)
        at com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage.createNativeModules(MainReactPackage.java:67)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.processPackage(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:793)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:730)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$600(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:91)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:184)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:169)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Try to replace React-Native dependency with latest version                 compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.39"  // From node_modules

Comment: did you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by gradle picking up the wrong version of react-native because of a wrong path in maven allprojects config (at least it was for us)
see PR here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/14743

Answer (score 0):

I was integrating an existing Android app (written on kotlin) with React Native.

The activity (.kt) I was writing to run the `ReactRootView` had the following `onCreate()` method:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mReactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(application)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index")
                .addPackage(MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState((LifecycleState.RESUMED))
                .build()

        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView!!.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null)
        setContentView(mReactRootView)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (!canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem was exactly on the line

`mReactRootView!!.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null)`.

I had to change the "module" name from 'MyReactNativeApp' to 'App', which is the name of my main component registered on React.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Sooo... the right `onCreate()` function is

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mReactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(application)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index")
                .addPackage(MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState((LifecycleState.RESUMED))
                .build()

        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView!!.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "App", null)
        setContentView(mReactRootView)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (!canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
```